# convert currency names to currency symbol

Tags: javascript

I need quick solution to convert currency names to currency symbols.

Like I have GBP which I want to convert into Pound symbol through small javascript/jquery code. Data is totally dynamic.

```
var currency_symbols = {
    'USD': '$', // US Dollar
    'EUR': '€', // Euro
    'CRC': '₡', // Costa Rican Colón
    'GBP': '£', // British Pound Sterling
    'ILS': '₪', // Israeli New Sheqel
    'INR': '₹', // Indian Rupee
    'JPY': '¥', // Japanese Yen
    'KRW': '₩', // South Korean Won
    'NGN': '₦', // Nigerian Naira
    'PHP': '₱', // Philippine Peso
    'PLN': 'zł', // Polish Zloty
    'PYG': '₲', // Paraguayan Guarani
    'THB': '฿', // Thai Baht
    'UAH': '₴', // Ukrainian Hryvnia
    'VND': '₫', // Vietnamese Dong
};
```

I can't use any plugin like `currenyformat`.

Looking for quick help.

Comment: [`Number().toLocaleString(undefined, {style:"currency", currency:"EUR"}).slice(0,1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString)

Comment: For currencies without symbols (and perhaps if a symbol is two characters): `Number().toLocaleString(undefined, {style:"currency", currency:"ZAR"}).split(" ")[0]`

Comment: The **correct** way to do this _without string parsing_:


`const getSymbol = currency => {
  const symbol = new Intl.NumberFormat('en', { style: 'currency', currency }).formatToParts(val).find(x => x.type === 'currency');
  return symbol && symbol.value;
}`

[Source: MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat/formatToParts)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Do this:

```
var currency_symbols = {
    'USD': '$', // US Dollar
    'EUR': '€', // Euro
    'CRC': '₡', // Costa Rican Colón
    'GBP': '£', // British Pound Sterling
    'ILS': '₪', // Israeli New Sheqel
    'INR': '₹', // Indian Rupee
    'JPY': '¥', // Japanese Yen
    'KRW': '₩', // South Korean Won
    'NGN': '₦', // Nigerian Naira
    'PHP': '₱', // Philippine Peso
    'PLN': 'zł', // Polish Zloty
    'PYG': '₲', // Paraguayan Guarani
    'THB': '฿', // Thai Baht
    'UAH': '₴', // Ukrainian Hryvnia
    'VND': '₫', // Vietnamese Dong
};

var currency_name = 'INR';

if(currency_symbols[currency_name]!==undefined) {
    alert(currency_symbols[currency_name]);
}
```

NOTE: Not every currency has symbol. Only listed above currencies have real symbol.

Comment: Of course these are not the only currency symbols. Russian Ruble for example : '₽',

Comment: I think you might be missing some: AUD CAD, AFN, BDT, etc.

Comment: This is more universal: a = 0; a.toLocaleString("en", {style:"currency", currency:"EUR"}).replace("0.00", "")

Comment: `toLocaleString` should be an answer

Comment: @Gottfried Unfortunately this doesn't work in all cases as-is. Some currencies do not have decimal places like the Japanese Yen, so the `replace("0.00","")` will not match, and you'll be left with "¥0". Forcing fractional digits seems to work, but there may be more edge cases I'm not aware of. Example: `a.toLocaleString("en", {style:"currency", currency:"EUR", minimumFractionDigits: 2, maximumFractionDigits: 2}).replace("0.00", "")` will result in the proper "¥"

Comment: Just in case somebody stumbles upon this post like I did, I recommend using the solution in comment by @Gottfried. I used it with `regex` to account for currencies that use 3 decimal places or none ( like `JPY` or other with any number of decimals) and `.` or `,` as separator. My solution was `a = 0; a.toLocaleString("en", {style:"currency", currency:"EUR"}).replace(/\d+([,.]\d+)?/g, "");` Of course @Android3000 suggested a solution already but it wont work for a currency with `,` as separator

Comment: if that mapping already exists in your browser, use the single source of truth. see @Gottfried 's answer but be smart about your assumptions. See also the [Intl API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat)

Comment: This works regardless of the currency decimal separator: `new Intl.NumberFormat('en', {style: 'currency', currency:'USD',}).formatToParts("1").find(part=>part.type="currency").value;`

Comment: This NPM package does the job nicely! https://www.npmjs.com/package/currency-symbol-map

Answer (score 5):

You could use a JSON to match the code with the symbol, here is a JSON to do so: https://gist.github.com/Fluidbyte/2973986

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/roine/3D4ZW/)

```
var data = {
// the json I gave you above
}
var code = $('input').val();
// the input which contains the code
$.each(data, function(i, v){
    if(i === code){
        $('#result').html(v.symbol);
        // #result is an empty tag which receive the symbol
        return;
    }
});
```

Comment: added fiddle with code sample

Comment: link is not working, can you provide working one