# HTML entity codes of Special Text characters getting Currency Symbols

Tags: javascript, react-native

How to convert currency HTML string into the symbol in JavaScript.
Here is the response from the API. 
For example `&pound;` need to be converted like `£`.

You can check my API response here:

```
>   getOptions: {
>             "FKP": "Falkland Islands pound (&pound;)",
>             "GBP": "Pound sterling (&pound;)",
>             "GEL": "Georgian lari (&#x10da;)",
>             "GGP": "Guernsey pound (&pound;)",
>     }


Please suggest. 
https://html-online.com/editor/

Following this link if you are click this link (just paste inside in this link  `&pound;` automatically converted pounds Symbol like £ )
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to convert? One currency to another or currency code to currency symbol.

Comment: still  i have 56 Currency codes  i want all are. Which i  am using Currency code that it will be Displayed Symbol

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373860/convert-currency-names-to-currency-symbol

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert currency names to currency symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373860/convert-currency-names-to-currency-symbol)

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://graphemica.com/%C2%A3

Comment: But in this case  in my Service response &pound; getting like this how can i convert this

Comment: HTML Entity (Named) &pound;     Convert to  £ . Not only this one Entire Currency Codes Converting  how it is possible

Comment: You are not clear with your question.

Comment: Please Check it once my Question , I modified Question

Comment: There are many different currencies that use the same name, hence the common use of [*currency abbreviations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) such as GBP, EGP, FKP, etc. Given £5.00, how does the viewer know which pound?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unescape HTML entities in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript)

Comment: @RobG he just wants to decode the html entity in the string he gets from his API. (e.g `getOptions["FKP"]`=>`"Falkland Islands pound (£)"`). Please [mjölnir this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912501/unescape-html-entities-in-javascript).

Comment: @Lavaraju Your question is still unclear. Why do you need the symbol in JavaScript? Are you going to display it in HTML?

Comment: @Buban Actually from Service response i am receiving  
`getOptions:{
"FKP": "Falkland Islands pound (&pound;)"
}` 
Now I want that String in As Currency Symbol  like this  £

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Finally I got a Absolute solution.
like Just i installed `npm install html-entities` this. After that When we are using on Particular place like that
Both two are giving this

```
const Entities = require('html-entities').AllHtmlEntities;

const entities = new Entities();
```

After that `console.log(entities.decode('&pound;'))` getting result Output like `£`

Refer this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities

Comment: If this is your answer, you should accept it so it can be referenced as a duplicate and also others know there's an accepted answer in search results.

Answer (score 0):

```
var currency_symbol={
        "FKP": "¤",
        "GBP": "£",
        "GEL": "₡",
        "GGP": "₲",
},

Now get it by--
 currency_symbol.FKP
 currency_symbol.GBP etc
```

Comment: but in my Service response like this bellow,

var currency_symbol={

        "GBP": "&pound;",
        "GGP": "&pound;",
},
if i am ging currency_symbol.GBP displaying &pound; in to text not showing Currency Symbol

Comment: Make sure that your document is in UTF-8,
and for more info you can try it on w3school.com

<p>I will display &pound;</p>

otherwise, i think you should customized your response.

Answer (score 0):

You are problably using the string in some kind of context that either escapes HTML control characters (such as `&`) or is not interpreted/displayed as HTML content, so the `&pound;` string will literally appear as such.

A workaround would be not to use HTML entities like `&pound;` but the actual Unicode characters for the various currency symbols:

```
getOptions: {
  "FKP": "Falkland Islands pound (\u00A3)",
  "GBP": "Pound sterling (\u00A3)",
  "GEL": "Georgian lari (\u10DA)",
  "GGP": "Guernsey pound (\u00A3)",
}
```

For your reference, see also this Unicode chart with [other currency symbols](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U20A0.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Intl to format, use the locale and currency code to select the format.

```js
var number = 123456.789;

// request a currency format
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'EUR'
}).format(number));
// → 123.456,79 €

// the Japanese yen doesn't use a minor unit
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('ja-JP', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'JPY'
}).format(number));
// → ￥123,457

// limit to three significant digits
console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-IN', {
  maximumSignificantDigits: 3
}).format(number));
// → 1,23,000
```

take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/NumberFormat) for more info

Comment: Did you try it with FKP?

Comment: The list of currency codes includes it (i didn't test), you can find the list of codes here: https://www.currency-iso.org/dam/downloads/lists/list_one.xml

Comment: In all implementations I tested, using FKP returns the currency code (i.e. FKP), not the symbol (£), which is not what the OP wants.