# API or angularjs service that gets currency symbol from currency code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, api

I'm looking for a service that when getting the currency code (from a database) will return the currency symbol.

Since it could be any country. I can't just do this :

```
{{product.price | currency: '£' }}
```

Example :

```
{{product.price | currency: 'EUR' }}   200 £
 {{product.price | currency: 'USD' }}   200 $
 {{product.price | currency: 'LAK' }}   200 ₭
```

is there any api that do this ? I can't change the database and add 100+ symbols.

Comment: Are you using angluarjs or angular 2+?

From memory could create a pipe/filter to put that value through.

Then have something like a switch/case to say

switch currency:
   case 'USD'
        return '$'
        break
   case 'EUR'
        return '€'
        break
    case default
        return '$'
        break

Comment: Consider [*convert currency names to currency symbol \[closed\]*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373860/convert-currency-names-to-currency-symbol). Note that many currencies share the same symbol, e.g. $ might be USD, AUD, NZD, CAD, etc. and £ might be GBP, EGP, LBP, SSP and so on.

Comment: @Adam91Holt switch case whith +100 countries? I don't think this is the right way to do it.

Comment: @RobG the comments under the answer helped. thx !

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by using a simple currency code / symbol map along the lines of:

```
currencySymbol = {
  'EUR': '€',
  'USD': '$',
  ...
}
```

then you use it by just referencing `currencySymbol['USD']`

several npm libraries offer you the exact same functionality with a broad list of currency symbols, such as [currency-symbol-map](https://github.com/bengourley/currency-symbol-map)