# How to display indian currency symbol in smart-cart plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

```
currencySettings: {
    locales: 'en-IN', // A string with a BCP 47 language tag, or an array of such strings
    currencyOptions:  {
        style: 'currency', 
        currency: 'INR', //USD
        currencyDisplay: 'symbol'
    } // extra settings for the currency formatter. Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString
}
```

Comment: Changes are done according to Indian currency but still displaying $ as currency.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19373860/convert-currency-names-to-currency-symbol

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question as needed.